# read multiple values based on cell address from a excel at once

Tags: r

if I have a vector of cell locations that a random strings:
data$list:
A11
C35
E58
AA7
...

and this vector has a long list (say 1000 different cell addresses)

can I read the cell values based on 1000 address from a excel at once? I am sure it must have a way but I haven't figured it out.

the only code I can think of is below, but it open the same excel each time to read the single cell, which is extremely slow.

```
excel <- ...
ws <- ...
n <- length(list[,1])

for (i in 1 : n) {
data$value[i] <- as.character(
                                  read_excel(path = excel,
                                             sheet = ws,
                                             col_names = F,
                                             range = data$list[1]
                                            )
}
```

enhance the R coding speed